# Error while adding WCF service reference Visual Studio 2010

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have VB.NET project and I created a WCF web service. I had the service added using Services References but then had a problem with a contract mismatch or something which I couldn't figure out so I decided to delete the service reference, rebuild the service code and add the service reference back. But now I am getting this error:

```
     There was an error downloading blah.
    The request failed with the error message:
--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The type 'InventoryExpressService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>The type 'InventoryExpressService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'InventoryExpressService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[InvalidOperationException: The type 'InventoryExpressService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.]
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +59318
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1434
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/InventoryExpress.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'InventoryExpressService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +499812
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean ensureWFService) +229
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +333
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean ensureWFService) +229
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +333
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b> Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446

            </font>

    </body>
</html>

    <!-- 
    [InvalidOperationException]: The type 'InventoryExpressService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
       at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
       at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
       at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
    [ServiceActivationException]: The service '/InventoryExpress.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'InventoryExpressService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..
       at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean ensureWFService)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean ensureWFService)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
    -->
    --.
    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: blah.
    The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.
```

I am wondering whether the problem is with the .svc file which has:

```
        <%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="InventoryExpressService.Service1" CodeBehind="InventoryExpress.svc.vb" %>
```

Where does it get the name "Service1" from? I can't find it anywhere else in my solution. That might be a red herring though. Any idea what might be going on? Thanks.

Comment: What did you name your new Serivice class?  Whatever that name is, replace Service1.

Comment: Have a look at the .svc file with notepad

Comment: Seems instead of renaming with refactoring, you have renamed file/ service from Service1 to another but some references are left. Make sure service name is fully qualified with namesapce & is correct.

Comment: I renamed it using refactoring, it changed it automatically in the .srv file. But I am still getting the error message: service could not be found. I wonder why they made WCF so un-user friendly?

Comment: OK I had a reference to the web solution in the service. I can't remember why I added it, but I removed it and now I can add the service reference! The mind boggles.